# Advantages of using JavaScript reduce compared to map function

Tags: javascript, reduce

Surely, there are plenty of questions to compare JavaScript `reduce` function to `map` function. But my question is exactly related to my issue, I should change an item inside a collection based on a condition, I can write in two ways, using `map` or using `reduce`:

```
// using map function

const formGroupModifierToMultiSelectLocation = (groups: Object[]) =>
  groups.map(({ components: cs, ...other }) => ({
    components: cs.map(({ type, ...rest }) => ({
      multiple: type === 'location',
      type,
      ...rest,
    })),
    ...other,
  }));
```

```
// using reduce function

const formGroupModifierToMultiSelectLocation = (groups: Object[]) =>
  groups.reduce(
    (acc, { components: cs, ...other }) => [
      ...acc,
      {
        components: cs.map(({ type, ...rest }) => ({
          multiple: type === 'location',
          type,
          ...rest,
        })),
        ...other,
      },
    ],
```

I prefer to use `map` because it is more readable than `reduce`. I don't know, maybe in my case using `reduce` has some advantages that I don't know them. In code-review, the reviewer proffers me to use `reduce` instead of `map`. I have no reason to change my codes.

Actual Question: **What are the advantages of using JavaScript reduce compared to map function in my case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` is helpful if you want to convert an array into an object. If you just want to modify an array, then `map` will work just fine.

As an example, consider an object of data where you want to remove a certain key.

```
const data = {
    a: 'x',
    b: 'y',
    c: 'z',
}

Object.keys(data).filter((item) => item !== 'b').reduce((carry, item) => ({
    ...carry,
    [item]: data[item],
}), {})
```